# Directly upload image from ios to php server folder with or without making post request

Tags: php, ios, image, http, server

i want to upload my image directly server folder.I just sent image data and image name and server folder path than image upload directly on server folder with given image name.

I am confused is it possible in http ,i can upload image at server directory without any at server code.

if its not possible in http than why? and if its possible in any other way than please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible. The reason is very simple security.

making it possible for everyone to upload files to your server would be very insecure, always go through web server apache/php or use an FTP, SCP command to copy the file securely to the server

Comment: About the security: HTTP has some in-built options for authentication too and it is possible for HTTP server to be only accessible from intranet.

Comment: True, still opening up a server folder directly to the outside world would be huge risk. Going through a web app at leasts blocks the server folder off. (at least if the code is written secure)

Answer (score 0):

As the server software don't by themselves handle the content of the request, you will need to write basic server-side code to handle the storage of image from the request. What it basically looks like

1. Read the image data from the *POST* parameters (in PHP something like $_POST["myImage"]).
2. Get access to the file system and to correct folder.
3. Write the data of image got on step 1 to location got on step 3.

There seems to be quite nice tutorial for this purpose on [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp).